does vault agent generate approle secret id after it expire?
I inject the role ID and secret ID of Hashicorp vault using Jenkins during the build stage of my app docker image.
Then, the vault agent read the role ID and secret ID connect to vault and deliver secrets to my app with vault agent templates.
Does vault agent generate new secret ID after TTL is expired, or should I use a Jenkins job to inject new secret ID periodically with Ansible.
I am using Ansible to deploy the app and couldn't figure out a secure way to pass the secret ID to the Hashicorp vault agent at run time, the container does not start without the secret ID being available.
My  Jenkinsfile:
                stage('vault') {
                steps {
                        dir ("./vault"){
        withCredentials([string(credentialsId: 'vault_django_role_id', variable: 'role_id'), string(credentialsId: 'vault_django_secret_id', variable: 'secret_id')]) {
                sh 'echo $role_id > django-role_id'
                sh 'echo $secret_id > django-secret_id'
                          }
                          sh 'docker build -t crns-vault:latest .'
                    }
                }
        }

I run the following commands in my vault server
data base secret
vault write postgres/config/crns \
    plugin_name="postgresql-database-plugin" \
    allowed_roles="django" \
    connection_url="postgresql://{{username}}:{{password}}@192.168.5.6:5432/crns" \
    username="admincrns" \
    password="crns@123"

vault write postgres/creds/django \
  db_name="crns" \
  creation_statements=CREATE ROLE "{{name}}" WITH LOGIN PASSWORD '{{password}}' VALID UNTIL '{{expiration}}'; GRANT all ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public TO "{{name}}"; \
  default_ttl="30s" \
  max_ttl="24h"

my approle command:
vault write auth/approle/role/django token_policies="django"

vault read auth/approle/role/django/role-id

vault write -f auth/approle/role/django/secret-id

my vault agent config:
pid_file = "./pidfile"

auto_auth {
  method {
    type = "approle"

    config = {
      role_id_file_path = "/vault-agent/django-role_id"
      secret_id_file_path = "/vault-agent/django-secret_id"
      remove_secret_id_file_after_reading = false
    }
  }

  sink {
    type = "file"
    config = {
      path = "/vault-agent/token"
    }
  }
}

template {
  source = "/vault-agent/secrets.tpl"
  destination = "/usr/share/django/secrets/.env"
}

cache {
  use_auto_auth_token = true
}

listener "tcp" {
    address = "0.0.0.0:8200"
    tls_disable = true
}

secrets.tpl :
{{ with secret "postgres/creds/django" -}}

DB_USER={{ .Data.username }}

DB_PASSWORD={{ .Data.password }}

{{- end }}

{{ with secret "kv/django/static" -}}

DB_ENGINE={{ .Data.data.DB_ENGINE }}

DB_DATABASE={{ .Data.data.DB_DATABASE }}

DB_HOST={{ .Data.data.DB_HOST }}

DB_PORT={{ .Data.data.DB_PORT }}

{{- end }}

I'm a newbie with vault but as I understand secret ID should be dynamic
does vault agent take care of that
or should I do that manually with a periodic job that will run Ansible ones a day or something
please note if something is not recommended in my set up.

Anything that's included in the Docker image can be fairly easily extracted back out.  You probably should not be including the Vault credentials in your image at all, but rather injecting them when you run the image.

I just changed the code so that the secret id is placed in a local directory so that it's mounted as a bind module when the container start(with ansible) , is that efficient?

That seems preferable.  For a single small file you'll read only once at startup, it's extremely unlikely you'll notice any performance impact from it.
